# Maildir permissions for courier

Tags: linux, permissions, courier

I'm having difficulty with maildir permissions for [**Courier**](http://www.courier-mta.org/), an IMAP server I've installed on a box running Debian Wheezy.

The mail directory I use is `/var/mail/users`, with the following permissions:

```
drwxr-sr-x 3 mail    mail 4.0K Oct 14 08:09 users
```

This directory has `chmod 750` permissions.

The individual *user* directories inside `/var/mail/users` have the following permissions:

```
drwx------ 6 johnsmith johnsmith 4.0K Oct 14 08:13 johnsmith
```

Note that the individual user directories are owned by the user, and have permissions of `700`.

The problem is that this causes courier to fail when it tries to access the user directories.  (The error message courier gives is vague, but I'm certain it's a permissions issue):

```
# telnet localhost 143
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION STARTTLS] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2011 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
0 LOGIN johnsmith@myhost.com mypassword
0 OK LOGIN Ok.
0 STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES UNSEEN)
0 NO [ALERT] STATUS failed
```

Note that the `STATUS` command fails.  Courier doesn't say why and there's nothing in `/var/log/mail.log`, but I'm 99% sure it's a permissions issue, because if I change the permissions on `/var/mail/users/johnsmith` to `777`, courier has no problem with the `STATUS` command and reports success.  But of course, I don't want to set permissions to `777`.

I thought perhaps the problem is that the `/var/mail/users/johnsmith` directory should be owned by `mail` instead of `johnsmith`.  So I tried doing that, but then courier fails on the `LOGIN` command:

```
0 LOGIN johnsmith@myhost.com mypassword
* BYE [ALERT] Fatal error: Account's mailbox directory is not owned by the correct uid or gid:
```

So what are the safest correct permissions I should set for the maildir (and maildir sub directories) so that courier can successfully login and access each dir?

Comment: have you tried setting user directories group to mail, with group `r-x` access ?

Comment: The courier project maintains a page devoted to debugging these types of issues, check that first: http://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/README.authdebug.html

Comment: @Archemar - yes, that results in `Fatal error: Account's mailbox directory is not owned by the correct uid or gid`